# How to display text and hyperlinks using i18next in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next

I have some dynamic content to translate which includes text and links in it, I wonder how do you use i18next in react native to display this content properly so the  tags shows clickable in the view.

```
{"someContent": "Hello, please click the <a>link</a>"}

import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
const {t} = useTranslation();
<Text>{t('someContent')}</Text>
```

The above just prints out the whole content not rendering the  tags. Wondering how to render this content properly in the view! I wonder can we use something like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "someHtml" }}`? If so, how to use in this case?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the `Trans` Component (you can find the official documentation [here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)).

In your case that means that your JSX code will look like this:

```html
<Text>
  <Trans t={t} components={[<a href="#whatever"/>]} />
<Text>
```

and in your EN.js file you would write:

```js
{
  "someContent": "Hello, please click the <0>link</0>"
}
```

You can put as many components in the `components` property as you wish and in the translation string you can then reference them by their index as I showed in my example (`<0>` and `</0>` to reference the first component).

Comment: How about custom link text ?